# Why isn't launchpad building my package?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, compiling, launchpad

I attempted to upload files to launchpad for building, using

```
dput ppa:sparhawkthesecond/ahm xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.8.2-1ubuntu2ahm0ly1_source.changes
```

It completed fine, and I was told that it was in the queue. I've been checking my [ppa page](https://launchpad.net/~sparhawkthesecond/+archive/ahm), but it's still coming up empty, about 8 hours later. From the [builders' page](https://launchpad.net/builders), under "PPA build status", it seems like wait time should be well under that. Currently, it says

```
amd64   44  46 jobs (10 minutes)
```

Has my package failed? And how can I check to see what the status of my package is?

FWIW, I tried uploading again, and it confirmed that this was fine.

```
$ dput ppa:sparhawkthesecond/ahm xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.8.2-1ubuntu2ahm0ly1_source.changes
Package has already been uploaded to ppa on ppa.launchpad.net
Nothing more to do for xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.8.2-1ubuntu2ahm0ly1_source.changes
```

I'm not sure if this is related, but I also attempted to import my OpenPGP key, but never got an email.

Comment: Did you get an email from Launchpad saying [PPA sparhawkthesecond/ahm] [ubuntu/trusty] xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.8.2-1ubuntu2 (Accepted)

Comment: No. (Also, as I mentioned, I didn't get any email about my OpenPGP key either.) The email address is fine.

Comment: Try to upload an ubuntu3 version, just update your changelog, buid the source package again and call dput. Usually it takes less than 5 minutes to get the notification from lp

Comment: Okay, I'm about to sleep (1:21 am here), but I'll give it a try in the morning. Cheers.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I realised there were some problems in the patch, so I uploaded a newer version anyway. I've waited 10 minutes but still nothing. This morning, the queue says `17 jobs (3 minutes)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to [import my Open PGP key into Launchpad](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/UploadErrors#The_upload_appears_to_work_but_I_don.27t_get_any_email_about_it) first (and possibly sign the code of conduct too). I forgot to upload the key to hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com.

Unfortunately, Launchpad doesn't give an error message about this when uploading packages.